# enable to run war grails session factory

Tags: hibernate, grails, multi-tenant

i've got error when trying to launch war on tomcat with multitenant

from logfiles:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]
    at grails.plugin.hibernatehijacker.hibernate.WrappedSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(WrappedSessionFactoryBean.java:45)

from my datasources:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true //true
    cache.use_query_cache = true //false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3

    //singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    naming_strategy = sn.kiyas.base.CustomNamingStrategy
    }
```

grails 2.4.4 apache-tomcat 7.0.79

Answer (score 0):

Remove these

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true //true
    cache.use_query_cache = true //false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3

    //singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    naming_strategy = sn.kiyas.base.CustomNamingStrategy
    }
```

And Add this

```
hibernate:
    jdbc:
        use_get_generated_keys: true
```